# What does the little number following "closed" signify in flag history?

Tags: support, closed-questions, flags, flag-history

I'm not quite sure what to search for on this, but I noticed a little number on one (and only one, so I couldn't pinpoint a trend) of my flags in my flag history.

The text appears as follows:

> title of question [closed] (1)

the flag was marked as helpful, the question was subsequently closed, yet a little (1) remains. I tried to see what that question had that the other questions did not, but moderator shut-down, specific tags, number of votes didn't matter. My only guess would be number of answers to the question? But I have no evidence for that. Does anyone know for certain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's simply the number of answers that the question has. If you hover over the number, it should give you a tooltip that says "1 answers" (yes, with the plural form of the word).

Comment: ahhh.. well that makes sense then! Thanks for the definitive answer and for catching the error in my title

Comment: <<runs off to submit pluralization bug>>